# Class constructor not saving variables

Tags: c++, class, oop, this

When trying to use a getter to obtain the value of the variable in my Employee class, nothing is returned or output.

I have tried using setters, which wouldn't do much as they still use the this-> method, but nothing reaches what I have set.

```
class Employee {
 Employee(int empNum, std::string name, std::string address, std::string 
phone);

private: 
 int empNum;
 std::string name;
 std::string address;
 std::string phone;
};

class HourlyEmployee : public Employee {
 HourlyEmployee(int empNum, std::string name, std::string address, 
std::string phone, double hourlyWage, double hoursWorked);

//getters
 double getHoursWorked();
 double getHourlyWage();

//setters
 void setHoursWorked(double hoursWorked);
 void setHourlyWage(double hourlyWage);

private:
 double hoursWorked;
 double hourlyWage;
}

//CPP file
Employee::Employee(int empNum, std::string name, std::string address, 
std::string phone) {
 this->empNum = empNum;
 this->name = name;
 this->address = address;
 this->phone = phone;
}
HourlyEmployee::HourlyEmployee(int empNum, std::string name, std::string 
address, std::string phone, double hoursWorked, double hourlyWage) {
 Employee(empNum, name, address, phone);
 this->hoursWorked = hoursWorked;
 this->hourlyWage = hourlyWage;
}

//main
HourlyEmployee hourly1(1, "H. Potter", "Privet Drive", "201-9090", 12.00, 
40.00);
cout << hourly1.getPhone() << " " << hourly1.getName() << " " << 
hourly1.getHoursWorked();
```

This is not the full code, but it should output the phone and name and the hours worked, but for some reason it is only outputting two spaces and then the hoursWorked. I can only assume that the name, phone, etc. variables have not actually been set, therefore they are not returning anything. So how do I get it to set those variables?

Comment: I'm really surprised you don't get a compiler error.

Comment: You shouldn't, it's just creating an unnamed temporary that blinks in and out of existence in one line. A warning on the other hand...

Comment: Please, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to see why you should post complete examples, instead of snippets of code.

Answer (score 4):

C++ doesn't treat constructor invocations specially in constructor bodies. The following line

```cpp
Employee(empNum, name, address, phone);
```

will construct a new, completely separate instance of `Employee`, and then discard it, because the resulting object isn't assigned to anything. The values of that object's fields aren't copied to the instance of `HourlyEmployee` you're creating.

To make use of the superclass constructor in the subclass one, use a [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) in the definition of the subclass constructor.

```cpp
HourlyEmployee::HourlyEmployee(int empNum, std::string name, std::string 
address, std::string phone, double hoursWorked, double hourlyWage)
        : Employee(empNum, name, address, phone) {
    this->hoursWorked = hoursWorked;
    this->hourlyWage = hourlyWage;
}
```

This way, C++ will invoke the constructor of `Employee` to initialize the same object that this constructor of `HourlyEmployee` is initializing.

You can even go a bit further and reduce your constructors to just member initializer lists. A nice side effect is that this avoids having to type `this->` or come up with different naming schemes.

```cpp
Employee::Employee(int empNum, std::string name, std::string address, 
std::string phone) 
        : empNum(empNum),
          name(name),
          address(address),
          phone(phone) {}

HourlyEmployee::HourlyEmployee(int empNum, std::string name, std::string 
address, std::string phone, double hoursWorked, double hourlyWage)
        : Employee(empNum, name, address, phone),
          hoursWorked(hoursWorked),
          hourlyWage(hourlyWage) {}
```

You can learn more from the link above, but to quote a short bit of explanation:

> Before the compound statement that forms the function body of the constructor begins executing, initialization of all direct bases, virtual bases, and non-static data members is finished. Member initializer list is the place where non-default initialization of these objects can be specified.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an *[initializer list](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/when-do-we-use-initializer-list-in-c/)* in the constructor of the subclass, like this:

```
#include <iostream>

class Employee {
public:
 Employee(int empNum, std::string name, std::string address, std::string phone) {
   this->empNum = empNum;
   this->name = name;
   this->address = address;
   this->phone = phone;
 }

 std::string getPhone() { return phone; }
 std::string getName() { return name; }

private: 
 int empNum;
 std::string name;
 std::string address;
 std::string phone;
};

class HourlyEmployee : public Employee {
public:
 HourlyEmployee(int empNum, std::string name, std::string address, std::string phone, double hoursWorked, double hourlyWage) 
 : Employee(empNum, name, address, phone) {
   this->hoursWorked = hoursWorked;
   this->hourlyWage = hourlyWage;
 }

 double getHoursWorked() { return hoursWorked; }
 double getHourlyWage() { return hourlyWage; }

private:
 double hoursWorked;
 double hourlyWage;
};

int main(void)
{
  HourlyEmployee hourly1(1, "H. Potter", "Privet Drive", "201-9090", 12.00, 40.00);
  std::cout << hourly1.getPhone() << " " << hourly1.getName() << " " << 
  hourly1.getHoursWorked();
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

> 201-9090 H. Potter 12

However, I strongly advise you use the initialization list for all your class's data members, namely both for the base and derived class in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor of the derived class HourlyEmployee calls the base contructor in a wrong way.

You should write the code like this:

```
HourlyEmployee::HourlyEmployee(int empNum, std::string name, std::string 
    address, std::string phone, double hoursWorked, double hourlyWage) :
    Employee(empNum, name, address, phone)
{
    this->hoursWorked = hoursWorked;
    this->hourlyWage = hourlyWage;
}
```

Also, the parameter name of all your constructors are same as your member names, this is NOT a good idea. Better name them differently.

Comment: No, he should put *all* the initializations into the initializer list.